# How to uninstall php70 or suppress homebrew error messages

Tags: macos, php, homebrew

Every time I open terminal on my mac, I get the following message from homebrew:

`Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php70" Please tap it and then try again: brew tap homebrew/php`

I have looked through a few different ways to resolve this outdated formula issue but nothing has worked. Is there a way to at least suppress this error message, as I think I have installed the correct php version, obviating the need to fix this

Comment: Try `brew doctor` to troubleshoot.

Comment: I tried that, but can't find anything related to PHP in the output

Answer (score 6):

I'm using ZSH and I had the same problem.
Every time I open a new terminal I had:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php70"
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap homebrew/php
```

In my ~/.zshrc I had this line:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php70)/bin:$PATH"
```

I removed that, since it is no more used and I have no more that warning message.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow you might still have a reference to the old path in your `.bash_profile` or equivalent.
When the line is removed, the message disappears.